# About the uniqueness of decimal expression of a real number

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, real-numbers

> **Definition**

> A sequence $(q_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of rational numbers is said a Cauchy sequence if for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb Q^+$ there exist $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that
> $$
> |q_m-q_n|<\epsilon
> $$
> for any $m,n\ge n_0$. In particular two Cauchy sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ are said $c$-equivalent if for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb Q^+$ there exists $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that
> $$
> |a_n-b_n|<\epsilon
> $$
> for any $n\ge n_0$

So it is not hard the above relation $\underset{c}\sim$ of $c$-equivalence is an equivalence relation so that it is possible to put
$$
\Bbb R:=\mathcal C/\underset{c}\sim
$$

For details about the last definition (of real numbers set) we refer to the text *Set Theory and Logic* by Robert R. Stoll.

So I'd like to discuss the proof of the following theorem which is taken from the mentioned text.

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $r$ be an integer greater than or equal to 2. Corresponding to each nonnegative real number $x$ there is a sequence $(d_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of integers which is uniquely determined by $x$ (relative to $r$) such that
>
> 1. $d_0=\lfloor x\rfloor$ the largest integer less than or equal to $x$
> 2. $d_n\in[0,r)$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$
> 3. the sequence whose terms are defined inductively by
>    $$
>    y_0=d_0\\
>    y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{d_{n+1}}{r^{n+1}}
>    $$
>    is a Cauchy sequence whose limit is $x$
>
> *Proof*. Let $r$ be an integer greater that or equal to $2$, $x$ be a nonnegative real number and $d_0=\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then
> $$
> xr=ar+x_1
> $$
> for some number $x_1\in[0,r)$. Let $d_1:=\lfloor x_1\rfloor$ so
> $$
> x_1r=d_1r+x_2
> $$
> for some number $x_2$ such that $x_2\in[0,r)$. Let $d_2:=\lfloor x\rfloor$ so
> $$
> x_2r=d_2r+x_3
> $$
> for some number $x_3\in[0,r)$. In general, define $x_n$ by
> $$
> x_{n-1}r=d_{n-1}r+x_n
> $$
> and set $d_n=\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then
> $$
> x=d_0+\frac{d_1}{r}+\frac{d_2}{r^2}+\dots+\frac{d_n}{r^n}+\frac{x_{n+1}}{r^{n+1}}
> $$
> where $x_{n+1}\in[0,r)$. Hence
> $$
> 0\le x-\Biggl(d_0+\frac{d_1}{r}+\frac{d_2}{r^2}+\dots+\frac{d_n}{r^n}\Biggl)<\frac{1}{r^n}
> $$
> According to the definition of $y_n$ given in $(3)$ this may be written as
> $$
> 0\le x-y_n<\frac{1}{r^n}
> $$
> It follows that $|x-y_n|<\frac{1}{r^n}$ whence $\lim_{n\in\Bbb N} y_n=x$.
>
> The proof of the uniqueness (relative to $r$) of the sequence corresponding to $x$ is left as an exercise

Moreover even the converse of the preceding theorem is true, that is

> Let $(d_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a sequence of nonnegative integers such that for some integer $r\ge 2$ and $d_n\in[0,r)$ for all natural numbers $n$. Then there exists a unique nonnegative real number $x$ such that the sequence whose terms $y_n$ are defined inductively by $y_0=d_0$ and $y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{d_{n+1}}{r^{n+1}}$ is a Cauchy sequence having $x$ as its limit.

So unfortunately I did not understand what is **the sequence corresponding to $x$ relative to $r$** so that I did not able to prove its uniqueness too. Anyway I think that this sequece cannot be the sequece $(d_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ because when $r=10$ it is well know that
$$
0.999999999\dots=1=1.000000000\dots
$$

So could someone explain to me which is **the sequence corresponding to $x$ relative to $r$** and why this sequence is unique? Perhaps is it possible that the sequence $(d_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is unique if the terms greater that $0$ are not all equal? Could someone help me, please?

For sake of completness [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY5Lo.png) the original text of the last theorem.

Comment: $r$ is the [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems#Standard_positional_numeral_systems) of the number system used for the representation of the relas: $2$ = binary, $10$=decimal, etc.

Comment: I know this. So what this can help me?

Comment: In point (i) the author states: $a$= the **largest** integer less than or equal to $x$.

Comment: Okay, and so? E.g. $2.3\neq 2.7$ but $\lfloor 2.3\rfloor=2=\lfloor 2.7\rfloor$

Comment: Where is my mistake? Forgive my confusion

Comment: Thus, for $x=1$ we must have $a=1$ and not $0$.

Comment: Okay, surely I agree but the same holds for $1.034$...

Comment: But what about $0.0\bar 9=0.1$ ? Here, we begin with the same integer part.

Comment: @Peter This is the point: so what Stoll want mean?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion about "The sequence corresponding to $x$ relative to $r$": The theorem proof constructs the sequence $(d_n)$.

Comment: @jjagmath Okay, so can you prove that the sequence $(d_n)_{n\in\Bbb N)}$ is unique?

Comment: You should copy more carefully, you didn't tell us what is $a$.

Comment: @jjagmath In Stoll's text $a$ is the integer part of $x$. I will edit the question. Forgive the mistake.

Comment: Obviously the theorem is wrong. As you observed, the decimal expansion is not unique, like in the case $x =  .1 = .0999\ldots$.

Comment: @jjagmath Question edited.

Comment: @jjagmath Okay, well. Anyway perhaps is it possible that the sequence $(d_n)_{n∈N}$ is unique if the terms greater that 0 are not all equal?

Comment: The theorem says the limit is unique, not the sequence.

Comment: @B.Goddard Nope. We're talking about this: "The proof of the uniqueness (relative to r) **of the sequence** corresponding to x is left as an exercise"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem is technically not wrong: it simply does *not* (in my opinion) state that decimal expansion (or expansion in any base) is unique.

The statement is "there is a sequence $(d_n)n∈\mathbb{N}$ of integers which is uniquely determined by $x$ [...]". It does not say that it is the only possible sequence. Just that we can define a sequence $(d_n)$ in a non-ambiguous way, knowing only $x$. Here the construction chooses to take the sequence ending with an infinity of $0$s instead of an infinity of $9$s in the case of a decimal number (or the equivalent in base $r$). This sequence is uniquely determined by $x$ and it satisfies all the properties, as the theorem states.

This being said, I do agree that the formulation is ambiguous, and maybe I'm trying too hard to salvage it. In particular, it is a crucial ommission from the author to not include a comment on the fact that decimal numbers admit two expansions. But if I had to be a judge on this statement's trial, I would have to rule that it is technically not incorrect.

Comment: @CapitainLama I agree with what you wrote: thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The theorems states the **uniqueness** of the sequence, so it's technically wrong.

Comment: The theorem says "there is a sequence ... which is uniquely determined by [some properties]". But that sequence is not always uniquely determined by those properties. So the theorem is actually wrong (not just technically).

Comment: @LeeMosher Okay, so it is wrong.

Comment: @LeeMosher It is not what is written. It is not said "uniquely determined by [properties]" but "uniquely determined by $x$, such that".

Comment: In $x=0.0\bar 9=0.1$ with $r=10$ ,  both representations satisfy the conditions of the theorem , nevertheless the sequence is not unique. Hence Lee Mosher is right, this is not just a technical flaw, it is a flaw.

Comment: You don't understand what I am saying. The sentence, grammatically speaking, does not say that the sequence is the unique one satisfying those properties. It says two things; a) the sequence is uniquely determined by $x$, b) it satisfyes those properties. If the author meant to say that the sequence is uniquely determined by those properties (impossible to know, I am not him), then the sentence is not grammatically correct.

Comment: @CaptainLama Well, I agree with you: effectively it is impossible what the author wanted mean and exactly for this I accepted your answer because it try to give a possible meaning to the sentence, meaning that obviously can not be accepted by all people.

Comment: @CaptainLama Anyway what is matter is have clarified that the sequence $(d_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not unique in general.